# How to properly import modules in Python with __init__.py

Tags: python-3.x, import

I have a folder structure like

```
app
├── modules
│   └── __init__.py
|   └── helper.py
|
├── tests
|   └── __init__.py
|   └── unittest.py
|
__init__.py
```

In the `unittest.py` I have a module imported like

```
from modules import helper

helper.do_something()
```

Unfortunately if I run `unittest.py` I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'helper' from 'modules' (unknown location)`. I'd appreciate a hint.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar project structure (main module folder containing source code folder as well as tests folder) and this is how imports are used in my tests:

```
from app.modules import helper
```

You could also use relative imports:

```
from ..modules import helper
```

It really depends on your needs and tastes.